# Do U.S. Air Force astronauts now become Space Force astronauts?

Tags: astronauts, military, space-force

Wikipedia has a [list of astronauts from the U.S. Air Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:United_States_Air_Force_astronauts).  With the creation of the Space Force from parts of the Air Force, **do these astronauts now become part of the Space Force?**  The question includes those who are active, retired, or deceased.

Comment: Hoping to get an answer from Digger.